# Custom headers based on taxonomies

Tags: templates, taxonomy

Got a bit of an issue that I require a little bit of help with if possible, I have been searching the net for the past day or 2 to try and solve (I have a feeling it will be an easy fix) I am just coming up short on a solution, let me explain:

I have registered a custom taxonomy which I have added 2 items too, which are selectable via the add / edit page in the admin menu.

I want to be able to tick the required box for the item on the page and then have the wordpress site display a custom header file for all pages with that taxonomy item selected.

I have created 3 individual header files (1 for each item and a generic one for everything else), then in the templates/header.php file I have put the following:

```
<? php
if ( has_term( 'item1', 'tax-name' )) {
    get_template_part('templates/headers/header1');
}
elseif ( has_term( 'item2', 'tax-name' )) {
    get_template_part('templates/headers/header2');
}
else {
get_template_part('templates/headers/header-generic');
}
?>
```

but this breaks the site by throwing a Server error 500 back at me. I have tried using switching statements with no avail.

I think it has to do with referencing the taxonomy but I am completely out of ideas.
Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry I should have explained. It throws a Server error 500 back

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted should do that. It is perhaps something in the header files themselves.

Comment: I think, you should use [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) with the optional `$term` parameter.

Comment: would you be able to give me an example to use by any chance Mayeenul?

Comment: `if ( is_tax( 'tax-name', 'item1' )) { get_template_part('templates/headers/header1'); }`

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's because you write <? php instead of <?php

Comment: -_- well that fixes the site breaking, Thank you Rubatharisan! school boy error! and thank you Mayeenul, I will give it a go :)